# Compilation Error SCSS: "Invalid CSS after..."

Tags: css, math, sass, division

I have been trying to use SASS for a project, but when I try to use the "math" module to do a division, the vscode console throws me the error that I leave in the capture.
As a compiler I use the Live Sass Compiler plugin.
I do not know if I am clear enough, I hope you can help me.

[code and console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3kC.png)

Greetings!

Comment: Next time paste code block instead of image.

Comment: Hi, please refrain from post your code as an image, post is as a formatted text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635). You can check out the [Stack Overflow editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to guide you on formatting your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 2):

A similar issue was introduced in bootstrap-sass 3.4.2:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/1228

To fix it, I had to rollback to 3.4.1 in my `package.json`:

```
"bootstrap-sass": "3.4.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Now we get an warn if try to do a division `$var / 2` for exemple.

To fix, first import 'math'

```
@use 'sass:math';
```

Then change all division (with `/`) to `math.div($var, 2)`.
Where the first element will be divide by the second.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replicate the error and fixed it by doing

`border-radius: $base-border-radius / 4`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Live Sass Compiler extension in vscode. I solved it using sass npm package instead.

1. Install sass globally

```
npm i sass -g
```

2. Watch your scss file --watch

```
sass --watch scss/styles.scss css/styles.css
```